# Songs events in python game

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to implement a game in python and i would like to have some effects songs in my game. I have done the following:

```
MusicStart.play()
MusicStart.stop()
```

I have assign all the details that needed. I want to play the song only one time. That i have done is repeated until the user press any input button.

Does someone know how to do it?

Comment: Start playing on an user action, disable the action. What is the problem ?

Comment: For example the starting song have duration 4 sec. the song doesn't play only 4 sec. i dont know why but repeated continuously until press a net input button

Comment: It seems like the play method have a loops arguments `play(loops=0)` from doc: `The loops argument controls the number of repeats a music will play. play(5) will cause the music to played once, then repeated five times, for a total of six. If the loops is -1 then the music will repeat indefinitely.`

Comment: you mean i will have something like this: MusicStart.play(0), i have tried but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Not completely clear about your question, but here's what I did to implement music in my game (pygame):

```
pygame.mixer.music.load(os.path.join('.', 'path-to', 'your-music-file.wav'))
pygame.mixer.music.play(0, 0.0)
```

That way, the music file plays once only. Note that `path-to` would be the sub-folder you have the music files in (*if* you have one: if the file is in the same directory as the code, skip it) and `your-music-file.wav` would be your file, whether it's an .mp3, .wav, etc.

You can see [the documentation page on it here.](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html)

Comment: Oh, and are you actually using *pygame* and not just coding a game in python?